# This particular element of the inertia may depends on these prime ideals?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Currently I'm reading an article. But since I'm not very experienced, I ended up getting stuck on a problem with the following lemma:

$``$Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number filed, let $\mathfrak p$ be a degree 1 unramified prime of $K$ with residue characteristic $p$, and let $L/K$ be an abelian extension that is ramified at $\mathfrak p$. Let $\mathfrak P$ be a prime of $L$ lying over $\mathfrak p$, and let $O_{L,\mathfrak P}$ denote the localization of $O_L$ (the ring of algebraic intergers of $L$) at $\mathfrak P$. Then there exists an nontrivial element $\tau\in I_{L/K}$ (the inertia group)
such that
$$\tau(\alpha)^p\equiv\alpha^p\quad(\text{mod }pO_{L,\mathfrak P})\quad\forall\alpha\in O_{L,\mathfrak P}\quad"$$

After the proof, the author starts to use this result as if the $\tau$ stated was not dependent on the $\mathfrak P$. i.e. he uses it as if there were such a $\tau$ with this property for all the prime of $L$ lying over $\mathfrak p$ simultaneously.

I'm starting to think that there is a very obvious reason for it not depending on $\mathfrak P$, and therefore the author don't even cared to mention. But since I'm not very experienced, I can not realize it.

The only point in the demonstration that really depends on the $\mathfrak P$ is when he evokes the completion of $L$ at $\mathfrak P$ (denoted $L_\mathfrak P$), to make use of the local Kronecker-Weber theorem and thus embed $L_\mathfrak P$ into a cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_m)$ (with $m$ minimal). After this he takes $\tau$ as being a generator for the cyclic group $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{m/p})}$, and then making use of some completely ok arguments, the desired $\tau$ will end up being this one restricted to $L/K$.

So maybe if somehow I could prove that the above $m$ is the same for all the $\mathfrak P$'s lying over $\mathfrak p$, it would be possible to conclude that indeed the same $\tau$ has the desired property for all the $\mathfrak P$'s lying over $\mathfrak p$. But I don't know even if it is true, and currently I have no idea how to handle it.

I hope my clarifications about the method of the proof are enough. But if someone needs, I can write down the whole proof of the lemma, so maybe it could become clearer.

I would appreciate so much any kind of help. 
I'm sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First $I_{L/K}$ should be denoted by $I_{\mathfrak P}$ because in general it depends on $\mathfrak P$. If $\mathfrak P'$ is another prime of $O_L$ above $\mathfrak p$, there exists $g\in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ such that $g(\mathfrak P)=\mathfrak P'$. This easily implies that $I_{\mathfrak P'}=gI_{\mathfrak P}g^{-1}$. As $L/K$ is abelian, we obtain
$$ \tau\in I_{\mathfrak P}=I_{\mathfrak P'}.$$
Let $a\in O_{L, \mathfrak P'}$. Then $g^{-1}(a)\in O_{L, \mathfrak P}$ and 
$$\tau(a)^p=(\tau g(g^{-1}(a)))^p=g(\tau(g^{-1}(a))^p) \equiv g(g^{-1}(a)^p)=a^p \mod g(pO_{L, \mathfrak P})=pO_{L, \mathfrak P'}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That is exactly what I needed.